# How to read YAML into list properly

Tags: python, yaml

So now im using this code to read YAML file. I've tried to separate `field_names` and `labels` into different lists. My problem is that the `field_names` and `labels` are one index lists now.

```
`print(field_name[0])`
```

print output is : ['neptun_code', 'result', 'mark']

But i would like to have this: `field_names[0] = neptun_code` ,`field_names[1] = result`, `field_names[2] = mark`.

My question is how can i read a yaml file into list properly.

```
import yaml

field_name = []
label = []
with open("cfg.yaml", "r") as stream:
    try:
        yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(stream)

        field_name.append(yaml_data['field_names'])
        print(field_name[0])

        label.append(yaml_data['labels'])
        print(label[0])

    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)'
```

Here is my YAML file:

```
field_names:
  - neptun_code
  - result
  - mark
labels:
  - Neptun code
  - Result [%]
  - Mark [1-5]
```

Comment: Use `.extend` instead of `.append` or assign the result directly.

Comment: Its working, thank you!